# Input Split always 2 in hadoop cluster HDinsight

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, azure-hdinsight

I deployed a 5 node hadoop MR cluster in Azure. I am using a bash script to perform chaining. I am using Hadoop streaming API, as my implementation is in Python.

My input data is always in one file but the size of the file ranges from 1 mb to 2 gb.

I want to create multiple mappers to handle this. I tried running using this command:

*yarn jar /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-streaming.jar **-D mapred.max.split.size=5000000** -files map2.py,red2.py   -mapper map2.py -reducer red2.py -input wasb:///example/${ipfileA} -output wasb:///example/${opfile}*

Here I have set my maximum split size to be 5mb.

I also tried to set my maximum block size to 5 mb.

However, when I run this, the number of input splits is always 2
mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2

And number of map tasks launched are also always 2.

I want the number of map tasks to be dynamically set based on the size of the data. What should I do?

Comment: Is your data and file format splittable? If not, you can't supply these values.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut How do I check? How do I make it splittable?

Comment: My input file format is application/octet-stream

Comment: So you need to implement your own custom input format that reads the binary stream and decides where to split it. Look at https://shrikantbang.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/hadoop-custom-input-format/ for some gentle introduction to the api.

Comment: Also not sure this will work with python, since Hadoop streaming is based on text.